# Sharepoint calendar web part not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a calendar web part in my SharePoint site which works fine in Firefox and IE but does not work in chrome browser.

This is the same situation i am facing.

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010programming.aspx?ID=9dde800d-7ce0-4069-93d7-2adf2c53d94b

Any suggestions ?

One more thing to add here is that , I have a content Query web part which will rotate the Promotions using JQuery cycle plug in. It is on the same page where I have put the list and library web part with calendar Month view as a default view.

If I remove that CQWP with Promotions everything works fine but if it there it wont work

Any suggestions? I have checked for the Jquery conflicts but could not find any of them .

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a custom master page?

Comment: Yes I have a custom master page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have find the root cause of my problem

There is one CQWP placed on the same page with this Calendar view list.

This CQWP ha call to jquery cycle plugin which will cycle the content after some interval , due to this JQuery conflicts my calendar control is not working in chrome.

Whem I Remove this CQWP everything works like  a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

1st, try to revert back to the OOB v4.master to see if the problem disappears. If it works as expected, this mean that your masterpage have some issue.

One of the most ridiculous bug in SP is that if you don't have the `SiteAction` control declared **before** the ribbon control, some javascript codes will fails.

In one of my custom master page, I have to create a second siteactions control, just before the ribbon control. I've put it into a invisible DIV to completely hide it from the user.

It ends with something like this :

```
  <SharePoint:SPRibbon ID="SPRibbon1" runat="server" PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"
                CssFile="">
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent ID="SPRibbonPeripheralContent1" runat="server"
                    Location="TabRowLeft" CssClass="ms-siteactionscontainer s4-notdlg">

<!-- Here is the hidden site actions control -->
                    <div style="display: none">
                        <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>"
                            ID="SiteActionsMenuMain" PrefixHtml="" SuffixHtml="" MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;">
                            <CustomTemplate>
                            </CustomTemplate>
                        </SharePoint:SiteActions>
                    </div>

                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
                            runat="server"
                           >

.... Removed for readability ....

                        </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
                        <div class="s4-die">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


                </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent runat="server" Location="TabRowRight" ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                    CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg">
.... Removed for readability ....
                </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
            </SharePoint:SPRibbon>
```

For your information, this behavior is due to one the inner control of the site action (PublishingConsole if I'm right). This inner control will produces some javascript global variable declaration (language and one another). This global variables are required by the ribbon control to works as expected.

Comment: Thanks For the help Steve but in my custom master page I have already defined the Site Actions. Still it is not working in CHrome browser

Comment: The important part in the answer is that the site actions must be present **before** the ribbon.

Comment: And did you tried to revert back to the OOB master page, to see if the master page is the guilty?